# encode raw-html to send as data with http post

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, base64

I am trying to send a JSON-string with HTTP-post. When i try to add raw-html data as text to the JSON-string i get server error 500.

This is my code:

```
 var data0 = $("#nameInput").val();
 var data1 = generateJSON();
 var data2 = $("#wellContainer").html();
 var jsondataobject = { name: data0, counter: counter, json: data1, html: escape(data2) };
 var stringobject = JSON.stringify(jsondataobject);

  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'text',
  url: "http://localhost:49162/Admin/SaveNewTemplate",
  data: "jsonData=" + stringobject,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (returnPayload) {
      console && console.log("request succeeded");
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     console && console.log("request failed");
      },

       processData: false,
       async: false
        });
         document.location.reload();
          //loadTemplate(data0);

         }
```

When i add html-data to the json-object with `$("#wellContainer").html()` i get 500 error. I have tried different html-content but i get the same error.

If i encode it to base64 with `btoa()` the http-post works, but `btoa()` does not support å ä ö characters.

How should i encode this? I need å ä ö characters.